# Fix TypeError: no implicit conversion of Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

```
=> #<Post:0x00009fc6099145ce8
 id: "224cc26e-6a66-43a0-89dc7d880f67",
 title: "Hello World!",
 context:
  {
   "language"=>"Japanese"
   "page"=>{"title"=>"Hello World!", "referrer"=>""},
   "browser"=>{"timezone"=>"Asia/Japan", "language"=>"en-US"},
   "campaign"=>{"source"=>"yahoo", "medium"=>"medium"}
  }
```

I'm trying to build an arel query to access the *timezone* field in column *context* which looks like

```
posts_join[Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("context->>\'browser, timezone\'")]
```

but I keep getting error

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral into Integer
```

On a similar note I'm able to access *language* field as

```
posts_join[Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("context->>\'language\'")
```

```
def posts_join
 users.join(:posts).on(posts[:user_id].eq(users[:id])).join_sources
end
```

How do I fix the query to access *timezone* field?

Comment: is `context`jsonb type?

Comment: yes it's a ```:json``` type @AmitPatel

Comment: Show the code of this method: posts_join, since Arel code doesn't return any error.

Comment: I'm using posts_join elsewhere as well and it works fine. Updated the code above